# How to present a backgound image with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an background image with css but I am geting 404 error

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:5500/css/img/example.jpg

Here is the code that I use.

```
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0,0.7)), url(img/example.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

The image is in the folder img and the name is correct.

Comment: `../` to go up one level: `../img/example.jpg`.

Comment: Is this path `http://127.0.0.1:5500/css/img/example.jpg` correct?

Comment: Please post your folder structure in the question - including html folder, css folder, image folder. Is the CSS in a file or in the html head?

Comment: @esqew suggestion solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The path may be correct, but not if the css is the starting point
So firstly you have to go up a level with "../" in front of your current path.
So "../img/example.jpg"

(Maybe you have to go up several levels, depending on where exactly your folder lies, you would need to show your folder structure for more insight if this doesn't fix it)

Answer (score -1):

If this is a CSS file, the image file is relative to the css file, not the html.

Answer (score -1):

`url` accepts the path relative to `/` (document root of the web server where website is deployed) or to the CSS file.

So if you change the line by adding `/css`:

`background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0,0.7)), url(img/example.jpg);`

to

`background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0,0.7)), url(/css/img/example.jpg);`

it should work. Absolute paths are usually better.

For more information please see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url

Comment: _"url requires path relative to / (root of the web server where website is deployed)"_ - no, it doesn't.

Comment: If it's an absolute path it does. @CBroe

Comment: It's called `root` in Nginx and `DocumentRoot` in Apache for example. @CBroe

Comment: But is is _not_ required to be absolute to begin with.

Comment: I get where you don't like it. Let me change the wording @CBroe